# RedirectToAction with new {@for = "SomeString"} what does this mean

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working on some code and the last coder is gone. I am looking for an explanation of the following in a C# controller.

```
RedirectToAction("SomeAction", "SomeController", new { @for = "SomeString" });
```

Specifically what does this:

```
new { @for = "whatever" }
```

actually do.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the parameter of the action, if you see the action definition it will look like this:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(string for)
{

}
```

in `RedirectToAction()` we are passing the parameter value to the action and later will be using it inside action, it can be some database id or anything.

This overload of RedirectToAction will be called:

```
protected internal RedirectToRouteResult RedirectToAction(
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    Object routeValues
)
```

and here is its implementation:

```
protected internal RedirectToRouteResult RedirectToAction(string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues)
{
 return RedirectToAction(actionName, controllerName, new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues));
}
```

[**Controller.RedirectToAction Method (String, String, Object)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460311%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

and this syntax `new { }` is called anonymous object or type. [**See Anonymouse Types**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx)

Comment: I will indeed look up the links for better understanding later. But if I understand what you say, my example essentially means... pass the string "SomeString" to the "for" argument of the action "SomeAction". Is this correct?

Comment: Just a note that the controller action would need to be `SomeAction(string @for)` since `for` is a keyword. That's the reason why it's `new { @for = "whatever" }`

Comment: @Shoe That's helpful...I was confused more because of the keyword so putting the @ in front of a keyword it turns it into a valid variable name. Is this right?

Comment: Yes the `@` sign allows you to use reserved words as variables. It's useful in cases where you do something like this `new { @class = "cssClass" }` without `@` you couldn't set the html attribute for `class`